# How to pass Order Invoice Number black to View in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel project an calling order controller using ajax call.After Order Successful I want to pass Order Invoice Number black to view .but I am unable to do that.Can any one help me???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller suppose

```
$order=order::create([
    'product_id'=>...,
...
]);

return response()->json($order);
```

In Fronted

And receive at AJAX success event

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "someaction.do?action=saveData",
    data: myKeyVals,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) { 
        var orderid=data.id;
    }
});
```